# How to serve django media files with docker and nginx?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, django-media

My setup for dockerizing & serving the Django app is a bit different when it comes to Nginx so the solutions I found didn't help.

I have dockerized the django app and its working fine except the media files. I am not using nginx inside the container but on the actual server. All the requests even static files are served perfectly except media files.
Here is settings for static and media:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_cdn')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  backend:
    image: gitrepo:latest
    #image: 731d5d7e9296
    ports:
      - 8400:8000
    links:
      - database
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate
      && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
      && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - media-cdn-data:/app/media_cdn
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

    tty: true

  database:
    image: "postgres:12" # use latest official postgres version
    env_file:
      - database.env # configure postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
volumes:
  database-data: # named volumes can be managed easier using docker-compose
  media-cdn-data:
```

This is my nginx file:

```
server {
       server_name app.platformname.com;
             location /media/ {
                 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8400/;
                 alias /app/media_cdn/;
             }
       location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8400/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_read_timeout 3600;
            proxy_set_header Connection '';
            # these two lines here
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
        }
}
```

Any help is appreciated,I have been struggling with it for the past 4 days :)

Comment: Any reason you're not running nginx via docker-compose too? Serving static and media files straight from the file system via nginx is the standard way, you'll need to mount a directory on the host machine as the media volume and then nginx can serve media files from that directory

Comment: hey Iain thank you for your reply. i have also added settings.py just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

Also i don't see you have any `nginx` block in your docker-compose file. Your

You have try this way both in your backend section and reverse proxy section

```
 - "./dist/static_cdn:/backend/static_cdn" # map physical machine
```

and in the nginx file add this:

```
 alias /backend/static_cdn;
```

Note: Please update your `docker-compose` file for nginx/reverse proxy similar to this

Why do you have to map with local physical machine instead of the container? coz, you will get permission denied error if you don't map with local machine to container

Comment: hey @anamul i have updated my settings.py.

Comment: @sh_07 I have updated the answer but you have to make sure your nginx in docker-compopse and map the memida root same way with both nginx block and backend block on docker-compose

Comment: ok ill try that but do you have any idea why static files are working with this config but not the media files?

Comment: I suspect your static file working becuase your setitngs.py file DEBUG=True, if you debug=False and then you have to fix the docker and nginx issue, otherwise, it will not works

Answer (score 0):

This is minimal example how to do this in few steps.

Configure your *nginx.conf* to serve media files directory such this:

```
server {
  location /media/{
    root /opt; # media files directory full path will be /opt/media
  }
}
```

Then you must configure your *docker-compose.yml* file to locate nginx to your project media directory path like so:

```
nginx-proxy:
  volumes:
    - ./your/relative/project/path/media:/opt/media
```

Now your nginx should see your media files directory.

E.g. your project contains files:

```
/your/relative/project/path/media
docker-compose.yml
```

Supposing your Django project is configured right (in your *settings.py* and *urls.py* media files serving is enabled).

Now you should get your media file by media file URL.